# Prior red notification for low quality posts queue

Tags: bug

When I finished to review the Low Quality Posts Queue, I noticed the Red notification that is displayed, as you can see below :

[image]

I tried to understand why it shows itself again, because I didn't do 20 reviews today, and even after refreshing the web page, it continues to be displayed.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK it indicates that a the queue has a certain amount of reviews that need doing, not that you personally need to do reviews in that queue, I am not sure what the actual,  numbers are, LQ has 17 reviews right now, perhaps that is particularly high right now, I don't know, someone better than me will be able to give a full answer. Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly